# Ripple animation on button press not occurring when java code is present

Tags: java, android, animation, material-design, imagebutton

I am attempting to create a calculator app. With only XML present a ripple animation like this occurs [image: ripple example]

However when I add java code, the ripple animation does not occur, everything else functions normally. Is their a way to fix this?

One button XML **(foreground tag houses animation)**

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/one_button"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_animation_grey"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/one_button_500_500"
        android:layout_below="@+id/four_button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**One button java code**

```
one_button_IB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!is_additon_selected) {
                    updateScreen("1");

                } else {
                    values.add(current_screen_value);
                    clearScreen("1");
                    is_additon_selected = true;
                    additionButtonActions();
                    System.out.println(values);


                }
            }


        });
```

Comment: The question is unclear. The animation you added shows a ripple backport library, there's no foreground attribute in the xml and the code is incomplete as there are method calls which can do pretty much anything.

Comment: @Zielony can you specify which methods you are talking about?